# SQL query - Self Join referring to common id

Tags: sql

How would I make an SQL query say displaying the name of (a particular name's) manager.
Use the following code for an example. I am only using one table.

```
select lastname
from staff
where employeeid = managerid AND last name = 'mclester';
```

The join I know, is where they have ID in common.
The syntax I used in this example is wrong, but I am trying to find Mclester's manager.
How would I write this query?
The logic is eluding me.

Thanks

Comment: Edit the question add some sample data & desired result would helpdul.

Answer (score 0):

This suggests me :

```
select s.lastname, ss.name as manager -- Use column whatever represents manager name
from staff s inner join
     staff ss
     on s.managerid = ss.employeeid
where s.lastname = 'mclester';
```